# Emacs get the list of functions in Perl file

Tags: emacs

I want to automatically generate an HTML document, containing docs for a Perl file. To build it I need a list functions, contained in the file. Every function has the format '^sub name'. Is there any function to get all function names? Or how to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use elisp search functions:

```
(defun find-perl-sub ()
  (let ((subs))
    (with-current-buffer "my-perl-file.pl"
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "^[[:blank:]]*sub[[:blank:]]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)" nil t)
        (push (match-string-no-properties 1) subs)))
    subs
    ))
```

Comment: I think, it would be better to replace `sub[[:blank:]]*` to `sub[[:blank:]]+`, because we need at least 1 space after "sub" keyword

Answer (score 3):

Note that extracting all the function names (together with their location in the buffer) is already done by *imenu*.
So you may prefer to use that.  Just call `imenu--make-index-alist` and then look at the result in `imenu--index-alist`.